# Evaluate a sub-formula of a formula

Tags: ms-office, office-js

After selecting a cell having a formula, we could select a part of its formula in Excel formula bar and calculate it (by pressing F9). I need to reproduce this evaluation of sub-formulas by JavaScript API.

For example, let's assume the values of Cell `A1`, `B1`, `C1` are respectively `1`, `2`, `3`, and Cell `D1` contains a formula `=A1+B1+C1`. I would like to be able to evaluate quickly a sub-formula such as `A1+B1`, `B1+C1`, and get the result `3` and `5`.

In VBA, under `manual` calculation mode, we could store the initial formula of `D1` in a variable, and then assign a sub-formula (eg, `=A1+B1`) to `D1` to get the result `3`, and then restore back the initial formula to `D1` like nothing happened; this evaluation does not raise calculation of any other cells that are descendants of `D1` (thanks to the `manual` mode).

However, with JavaScript API, the re-calculation only works under `automatic` mode. If we assign a sub-formula (eg, `=A1+B1`) to `D1`, all the cells that are descendants of `D1` are re-calculated by `ctx.sync`, which may be costly.

So is there a way or a workaround to optimise that?

One possible workaround is to find an isolated cell in the workbook that no cell depends on (eg, a cell outside `usedRange` of a worksheet, but we still need to make sure no cell depends on it, because of the nature of `usedRange`...), and then assign a sub-formula to that cell and get the value. The disadvantages of this approach are

1) it's still a hack, and modifies the area of a worksheet.

2) a User-Defined Function (if programmed badly) may rely on the dimension of a worksheet or the position of the cell holding it. In this case, evaluating a user-defined function in an isolated cell may lead to different result (or side effects) from the evaluation in the original cell.

Could anyone help?

Comment: I'm interested to learn more about this add-in you're building with so many capabilities and API features being used. If you'd like to demo or share your ideas, reach out to me at exceladdins@outlook.com and I'll provide my work email address. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your interest and thanks to @MichaelZlatkovsky who constantly answer to my questions. I consider it a privilege to directly address Microsoft team and appreciate it a lot. Actually, I have developed an "engine" in OCaml before, and for 1 month I have been developing Excel JavaScript add-ins as "interface"; I have already submitted 2, and am developing the third one (so not all the capabilities are in one single add-in). I will reach you out very soon when I think my add-ins are presentable, and am happy to keep working closely (and remotely) with you guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first approach that you list is probably the easiest.  Namely, reead the formula of the cell and save it as a javascript variable (string). Next modify the formula in place, issue a load on the value, and then revert the formula back to the save string.  The only true disadvantage of this approach is that you're messing with someone's formula, which means that if something goes wrong between step 1 and step 2, you leave the document in a dirty state.  And, as you say, it may have downstream impacts (perf-wise) on calculations.

Alternatively, if you actually *know* what formulas are there, you could use the "worksheet functions" feature.  For example, here you're calculating the sum of 20 + the sum of two worksheet ranges.

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var result = ctx.workbook.functions.sum(
        20,
        ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("F3:F5"),
        ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("H3:H5")
    ).load();

    return ctx.sync();
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

This is the "cleanest" way to calculate in that it doesn't impact the worksheet state, and you can even chain the calculations:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("E2:H5");

    var sumOfTwoLookups = ctx.workbook.functions.sum(
        ctx.workbook.functions.vlookup("Wrench", range, 2, false),
        ctx.workbook.functions.vlookup("Wrench", range, 3, false)
        );
    sumOfTwoLookups.load();

    return ctx.sync();
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

The downside is that this won't work with UDFs (and with array formulas, for that matter), and that you sort of need to know a-priori what sort of formula the cell consists of.  But if you're talking about calculating a sub-formula of the formula, I assume you already have some information on the formula within, so the latter may not be a problem.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting, I didn't know "worksheet functions"... One remark is I have not found the functions for `-`, `/` and `+`, `*` (rather than using workarounds such as SUM, PRODUCT). If they don't exist, it seems that we have to do `ctx.sync` two times to realise `SUM(1,SUM(3,4)-2)`, because we cannot write directly `var result = ctx.workbook.functions.sum(1,ctx.workbook.functions.sum(3,4)-2)`...

Comment: I asked [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337870/worksheet-function-for-division-of-real-numbers-ie) for that...

Comment: For this and many other scenarios what is really needed is the equivalent of VBA Application.Evaluate and Worksheet.Evaluate (preferably with a few less bugs than the VBA evaluate)

Comment: @Charles, I agree that it would be ideal if we could.  But in practice `Application.Evaluate` is very much tied to the VBA/desktop implementation (and also allows you to evaluate formulas that wouldn't be valid on other platforms, and/or ones that rely on other opened books (which also wouldn't work for something like the web), etc etc.).  Hence isolating just the pure functions was the more doable task, at least as a first step.

Comment: @Michael - not sure that is correct - my understanding is that Evaluate just hooks into Excel's formula interpreter/evaluator - which exists on all platforms. And I am not aware of any valid Excel formulas that are  only valid on some platforms - could you give an example?