# Worksheet function for division of real numbers (ie, /)

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I have not found division of real numbers (ie, `/`) in [worksheet functions](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/functions). As a consequence, to evaluate `=SUM(2,SUM(30,40)/3)`, we cannot use one expression `ctx.workbook.functions.sum(1,ctx.workbook.functions.sum(30,40)/3)`;
we have to do `ctx.sync` two times:

```
function test () {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var result = ctx.workbook.functions.sum(30,40);
        var result2;
        result.load();
            return ctx.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    result2 = ctx.workbook.functions.sum(1,result.value/3);
                    result2.load(); })
                .then(ctx.sync)
                .then(function () {
                    console.log(result2.value); });
    }); 
}
```

That means, if there are several `/` in one expression, we have to use even more `ctx.sync` to evaluate it, which is very tedious (and especially hard to be automatically constructed).

So it would be really great to either find the worksheet function or a workaround for `/`, so that we could still evaluate an expression containing `/` in one step.

PS: it seems that there is no worksheet function for `+`, `*`, `-` either, but we could use workarounds: `sum` for `+`, `product` for `*`, and `sum(..., product(-1, ...)` for `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a combination of the `product` function and the `power` function with the exponent -1. This solution will work even if the denominator (divisor) is a variable and not a constant.

```js
var myNumerator = 888, myDenominator = 4;
var funcs = ctx.workbook.functions;
var result = funcs.product(myNumerator,funcs.power(myDenominator,-1));
```

In your specific example to evaluate `=SUM(2,SUM(30,40)/3)`, the code would be:

```js
result = funcs.sum(2,funcs.product(funcs.sum(30,40),funcs.power(3,-1)));
```

Comment: I don't think I would have thought of this capability without your postscript anyway, so thanks for adding some new tricks to our API arsenal :)

Comment: Very cool indeed.  @SoftTimur, note that these functions chain in a way that any function accepts a previous function's result, so you can do the calculation just like Michael Saunders wrote it above, with only a single ".load" and ".sync" at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

At least for dividing by a constant (e.g., 3), isn't that the same as `product(something, .33333333)`

Comment: I don't know the dividend and the divisor... So now, to answer [my previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329416/evaluate-a-sub-formula-of-a-formula), theoretically, given any sub-formula, we could construct automatically one string with worksheet functions, and then use `eval` and `ctx.sync`... glad to know it is doable... thanks for your help...